# Webpack css loader configuration outside of webpack.config?

Tags: git, reactjs, webpack, css-loader

I'm using webpack and css-loader with a React app, which is running fine on the webpack dev server in the original directory where I wrote it. However, after pushing to git and cloning the repository the cloned version doesn't load css (details below).

Are there places where webpack loaders can be configured other than webpack.config.js, package.json, package-lock.json? Or, any ideas on why the behavior would be different in a copy of the app? I tried this without a .gitignore to make sure I wasn't stripping anything so all files should be the same.

Edit: now after running the copy on the dev server the original is not working either, so I'm looking for something getting cached.

---

More details:

After cloning I found out I was using incorrect loader syntax, since the '-loader' is now required in webpack.config.js. For some reason it works in the original copy, but both instances are on webpack 3.8.1 and css-loader 0.28.7. (And since package.json, package-lock.json, and / node_modules are all in git, everything should be the same version - right?)

**This works in my original repository:**

```
webpack.config.js:
(...)
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: 'css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
},
```

but causes this error in a cloned directory:

```
BREAKING CHANGE: It's no longer allowed to omit the '-loader' suffix when using loaders.
             You need to specify 'css-loader' instead of 'css',
             see https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#automatic-loader-module-name-extension-removed
 @ ./app/components/GroupTable.js 3:0-37
 @ ./app/components/MainView.js
 @ ./app/components/App.js
 @ ./app/index.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8081 ./app/index.js
```

so I updated it to this:

```
webpack.config.js
(...)
{
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
    },
```

When I add the '-loader' webpack.config.js, css isn't loaded as it was before. There are no other tests in webpack.config that evaluate to true for .css files.

The config files I'm aware of (webpack.config.js, package.json, package-lock.json) are the same between the two copies, so I'm trying to find out what else could cause differences in behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone finds this question, it looks like there is **not** configuration outside of the files listed above. I believe the problem is that I hadn't rebuilt from webpack after making changes to the css loader, so didn't realize I had broken it. I ran build in the copy from git, so it used the config as received, which was broken.

That addresses the question of whether there's a hidden config, which there doesn't seem to be. I'm still not sure why this loader doesn't work:

```
loader: 'css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
```

but in the meantime this does:

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
},
```